# Find odd numbers in a list and square them using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Here is the code I have got so far. Now output is `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]`

````
N = 10
for i in range(1, 10):
    arr.append(i)

arr2 = []
f = lambda x: x ** 2
arr2 = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, arr)
map(lambda x: x ** 2, arr2)
print(list(arr2))```
````

Comment: Why use a lambda instead of list comprehesion?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse That's the task.

Comment: You got the `filter` part right. The second part should probably be done using `map` in a similar way.

Comment: Are you supposed to only return the odd squares or the original list with the original evens numbers and squared odd numbers?

Comment: @MarkMeyer only odd ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are discarding the result of `f(i)` as soon as you create it. You need to append it to some list (also, no need to consume the `filter` object into a list):

```
result = []
for i in arr2:
    result.append(f(i))
```

Please note that binding a lambda to an identifier is discouraged in accordance with [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations).

The best way to solve this problem is without list comprehensions is a combination of `filter` and `map` like so:

```
arr2 = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, arr)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your last for-loop applies the lambda function to the elements in your list, but does not save the result. 
Try:

```
a = [i for i in range(1,10)]
a2 = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, a)
a3 = map(lambda x: x**2, a2)        # This is a generator object
final_list = list(a3)               # This is a list
```

[Python Tips on map filter reduce](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#filter)

Comment: Add a call to `list` at the end, or OP will be confused when they try to `print(a3)`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very slightly modified version:

```
arr = []
N = 10
for i in range(1, N):
    arr.append(i)

arr2 = []
f = lambda x: x ** 2
arr2 = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, arr)
for i in list(arr2):
    print(f(i))
```

`arr2` isn't a list. It's an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter), which you can only convert to a list once.

Here's a more compact version:

```
N = 10
arr = range(1, N)

square = lambda x: x ** 2
keep_odd = lambda x: x % 2 != 0
arr2 = list(filter(keep_odd, arr))
for i in arr2:
    print(square(i))

print(arr2)
```

It outputs:

```
1
9
25
49
81
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't saving the value in the array, you are just printing it.

```
N = 10
for i in range(1, 10):
    arr.append(i)

result = []
f = lambda x: x ** 2
arr2 = filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, arr)
for i in arr2:
    result.append(f(i))    
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]

ans = list(map(lambda x: x ** 2, filter(lambda x: x % 2 != 0, lst)))

print(ans)
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.